# Running time of a recursive function with two inputs

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

I've been solving some interview questions, practicing and I am still struggling a bit to determine the running time of some recursive functions.
The question I was solving is:

> Imagine a robot sitting on the upper left corner of an X by Y grid.
>   The robot can only move in 2 directions: right and down. How many
>   possible paths are there for the robot to go from (0, 0) to (X, Y)?

My solution (in Java):

```
public int totalPossiblePaths(int X, int Y) {
    if(X < 0 || Y < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(X == 0 && Y ==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return totalPossiblePaths(X - 1, Y) +
           totalPossiblePaths(X, Y - 1);
}
```

Furthermore, I did an analysis on space and time complexity of this program, in terms of big-Oh as an interview would require me to know.
I came to the conclusion that the space complexity is:

> O(X + Y)

Since there would be at most X recursive calls followed by Y recursive calls so at most X+Y function calls would be pushed on the stack.

However, the running time complexity isn't very clear to me.
I have drawn the recursion tree and it is obvious that the recursion is (at least) exponential.
I just cannot seem to find for sure the relationship between X and Y.

Sample recursion (without calls that have X<0 or Y<0 for readability):

> ```
>     F(3, 2) = F(2, 2) + F(3, 1)
>             = F(1, 2) + F(2, 1) + F(2, 1) + F(3, 0)
>             = F(0, 2) + F(1, 1) + F(1, 1) + F(2, 0) + F(1, 1) + F(2, 0) + F(2, 0)
>             = F(0, 1) + F(0, 1) + F(1, 0) + F(0, 1) + F(1, 0) + F(1, 0) + F(0, 1) + F(1, 0) + F(1, 0) + F(1, 0)
>             = F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0) + F(0, 0)
> ```

The last level has 10 elements (returning value 1) which is the number of possible paths to reach (3, 2) from (0, 0).
From my intuition, I would think that the running time grows with respect to X and Y as such:

> O(2^X * 2^Y) = O(2^(X + Y))

Additionally, I added a counter that increments with each recursive call to see how many times the function is called. For the example above, function is called 49 times.
The function successfully passes the two `if` statements 24 times and attempts to make 2 more recursive calls.

This leads me to further doubt my intuition.

Can anybody help me with how to analyze this (and similar) recursive functions to determine time complexity?
I am not looking for you guys to bother explaining me in depth of how to solve this, but perhaps some general pointers or advice? Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that the expected approach is the one you took. A path from the upper left to the lower right corner always consists of `X+Y` down (D) or left (L) steps, of which `X` times left and `Y` times down. For instance, for `X = 3` and `Y = 2`, this is one possible path: `LLDLD`. The question is: how many different sequences exist? In other words, in how many ways can you pick `X` times `L` out of `X+Y` positions? Combinatorics tells this is `X+Y choose X`, or `(X+Y)!/(X!Y!)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 
My solution just goes backwards from (X, Y) to (0, 0) by taking the left and up moves which would be opposite to starting at (0, 0) and going to (X, Y) by moving right and down.

For X = 3 and Y = 2, my solution gives 10.

(X + Y)! / (X! Y!) would give (5)! / (3! 2!) = 10

Comment: Looks like the recursion for [Ramsey numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Asymptotics) to me. Those grow pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky, and every problem is different. Start with a spreadsheet that calculates the number of calls to get a feel for the problem.

If you start with X = Y > 0, do recursive calls X + Y levels deep, then there are 2^(X + Y) ways which of the two recursive calls you could have chosen. Many of those ways wouldn't go X + Y levels deep because either X or Y becomes negative. But if you follow each call path the same number of times, then you will go X + Y levels deep. There are (2X over X) ways to do this, which is about 2^(X + Y) / sqrt (pi X).

Comment: Thank you. This is along the lines of what I was looking for.

Comment: Could you explain where the root of pi*X comes from? Is that an application of Stirling's approximation? Also, how does Y come into a term for 2X over X?

Comment: Yeah, any further explanation is much appreciated :)

Comment: Ah, found it, you were still talking about if X = Y; then what you give is in fact a result of an application of Stirling's approximation and can be found [on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas).

Answer (score 0):

What number of summands does it take to have sum `S` when every summand is `0` or `1`? Well, it is obviously at least `S`. So, your function makes at least `answer` calls where `answer` is the answer to the problem. That would be the exact count if you returned only ones, and handled zeroes otherwise.

*For the record, a good solution for the problem has a lot to do with [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) (this particular [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPascal%27s_triangle_pathways.svg) may help).*

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution: To go from (0, 0) to (x, y) it has to take x + y steps in total. Of those you have to select the positions of the x horizontal steps, which you can do in binomial(x + y, x) ways.

Comment: I appreciate you guys providing alternative solutions.
It definitely helps me look at the problem from different angles.
However, I want to find the the running time of the solution I created, not particularly if it is optimal.